Why is Excel formula bar displaying cell reference and not the formula?
For some reason a spreadsheet that was working fine is now displaying the cell address, including full file path of the spreadsheet, i.e. not the formula or the result

Does Display or hide formulas - Microsoft Support asnwerr your question?

For future reference, it also helps to include a screenshot of the current condition and sometimes even the desired condition if you can mock it up.

If the Formula Bar in Excel displays cell references instead of formulas, it may be due to a change in settings. Click on the Formula Bar, find the downward arrow icon, and choose "Formula" instead of "Show Formula Auditing Toolbar." If that doesn't resolve the issue, try resetting Excel's settings by going to File > Options > Advanced. Make sure that "Show formulas" is unchecked under the Display options for this workbook. Restart Excel to ensure the changes take effect and that formulas are displayed correctly in the Formula Bar.
